# Java - Scanner - Skips over my last nextLine() request

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So I instantiate the `Scanner scan` a lot earlier but it skips right over my second `scan.nextLine()` after `scan.nextInt()`. I don't understand why it skips over it?

```
     System.out.println("Something: ");

        String name = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Something?: ");

        int number = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Something?: ");

        String insurer = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Something?: ");

        String another = scan.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 7):

because when you enter a number

```
    int number = scan.nextInt();
```

you enter some number and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, it only accepts number and keeps new line character in buffer

so `nextLine()` will just see the terminator character and it will assume that it is blank String as input, to fix it add one `scan.nextLine()` after you process `int`

for example:

```
 System.out.println("Something?: ");

 int number = scan.nextInt();

 scan.nextLine(); // <--
```

Answer (score 5):

When you call `int number = scan.nextInt();` it does not consume the carriage return that has been pushed, so this is does at the next `scan.nextLine();`

You want your code to be

```
    ....
    System.out.println("Something?: ");
    int number = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();                      // add this
    System.out.println("Something?: ");
    String insurer = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: Or quite possibly `int number = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());` readInt will only read a single digit number.

Answer (score 5):

- The method `nextInt()` will not consume the new line character \n. This means the new line character which was
  already there in the buffer  before the `nextInt()` will be ignored.
- Next when you call `nextLine()` after the `nextInt()`, the `nextLine()` will consume  the old new line
  character left behind and consider the end, skipping the rest.

[image]

Solution

```
int number = scan.nextInt();
// Adding nextLine just to discard the old \n character
scan.nextLine();
       
System.out.println("Something?: ");
String insurer = scan.nextLine();
```

OR

```
//Parse the  string to interger explicitly 

String name = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("Something?: ");
String IntString = scanner.nextLine();

int number = Integer.valueOf(IntString);
System.out.println("Something?: ");
String insurer = scanner.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

All answers given before are more or less correct.

Here is a compact version:

What you want to do: **First use `nextInt()`, then use `nextLine()`**

What is happening: While `nextInt()` is waiting for your input, you press `ENTER` key after you type your integer. **The problem is `nextInt()` recognizes and reads only numbers so the `\n` for the `ENTER` key is left behind on the console.
When the `nextLine()` comes again, you expect it to wait till it finds `\n`. But what do you didn't see is that `\n` is already lying on the console because of erratic behavior of `nextInt()`** [This problem still exists as a part of jdk8u77].

So, the nextLine reads a blank input and moves ahead.

Solution: **Always add a `scannerObj.nextLine()` after each use of `scannerObj.nextInt()`**